# How to delete multiple files and directories in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix

I have very little knowledge about unix.

My task is to write a shell script to delete multiple files and directories.
All files and directories have different location.

So can i use this logic of creating an array and storing all the paths in that.Then looping around the array and use rm command with each element of array.

I dont have unix system to practice commands, hence i was not able to test it. Is this the correct way? or what else could be done

Thanks a lot.

Comment: First put yourself into practice and come with your specific query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can do it this way.

The rm command can take multiple arguments to delete multiple files/directory in one command.
So, instead of calling rm once per entry in your array, you can call it only one time with all the files in your array as parameter.

If you have a lot of files to delete, be careful because there is a command line length limit. (you can get it by executing "getconf ARG_MAX" )

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean linux, which is a unix-like system.

If you're not going to search for the files and directories to be removed, then you could put them in an array and loop through it if you want to.

If you're going to search for them, just delete something as soon as you find it.

Also, don't post vague questions.